# rails 6 ajax "remote: true" does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I had a working application when I went to bed, and when I booted it back up this morning, the AJAX no longer seemed to work, and remote:true does not seem to do anything. I have spent most of the day trying answers to related questions to no avail.

In categories/index.html.erb (set as root), I link to the SHOW request for each category, and the container for the result, referenced in categories/show.js.erb

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <li>
        <span>
        <%= link_to category.name, category, remote: true %>
        </span>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>    
</div>


<div id="somevehicles">

    This should load the contents of category/_show.html.erb

</div>
```

The show.js.erb:

```
$('#somevehicles').html("<%= j render 'categories/show', category: @category %>")
```

The _show.html.erb:

```
<% @category.vehicles.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.name %>
<% end %>
```

in categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
.
.
.
  def show

  end
.
.
.
```

When I run the rails server in dev i recieve no errors. Instead, when I click on the rendered `<%= link_to category.name, category, remote: true %>`, it takes me to show.html.erb(no underscore), which is where it would go if there were no `remote:true` at all. Before, even without complete AJAX or a corresponding .js.erb, adding `remote:true` to the tag made it so the link went nowhere, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED BY ACCIDENT:

I switched to every git commit, starting from my first confirmed working version, ending back at the most recent version that I opened this morning. All I did was git checkout, ran `yarn install --check-files` if required after running `rails s`, and testing to see if the AJAX worked.

After reverting back to the most recent version and running the rails server, everthing worked. So, the fix was to turn it off and back on again. That or `yarn install --check-files`.